# Need explanation for 'convention over configuration'

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox, fw1

I saw 'convention over configuration' in most of the CF frameworks. Could anyone please explain this with example? I got a different answer from different people. So, I little bit confused.

Why fw1 is 'convention over configuration'?

Comment: This is just a general term for having an application structure that adheres to conventions, while the configuration approach basically means that you need to setup everything the way you want it to work. People will tell you different definitions because there is no single definition.